# Eclipse stating that isntall directory is location of JAVA_HOME

Tags: java, eclipse, windows, installation

I was trying to setup a workspace for modding in Minecraft, and got a error stating that my JAVA_HOME directory was not found. After messing around and installing a new JDK, running Eclipse states that:

"A Java Runtime Enviroment (JRE) or Java Development Kit (JDK)" must be avaiable in order to run Eclipse. No Java virtual Machine was found after searching the following locations: C:\Users\|My Username|\Desktop\Eclipse\jre\bin\javaw.exe
javaw.exe is your current PATH"

I was checking my PATH and JAVA_HOME variables, which where both set to C:\Programm Files(x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_51
The file eclipse is looking for is the standart directory where java stores its javaw.exe, i.e Java\jdk1.8.0_51\jdk\bin\jawaw.exe, but Eclipse is somehow thinking my path is set to the Eclipse installation directory. Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a bad idea to have JAVA_HOME set to a folder in "c:\program files..." because of the space in the folder name. Whenever this value is used as a command line argument, the receiver would interprete it as two arguments ("C:\program" and "file...").

Move your jdk into a folder without space in the name, and correct your JAVA_HOME variable.

BTW: eclipse resolves first the system PATH variable in order to find a suitable java SDK. It's a good practice, to declare the desired SDK in the eclipse.ini file (in eclipse install-folder). Add there an argument:

```
....
-vm 
C:\JDK8\bin\javaw.exe
-vmargs 
-Xms40m 
-Xmx384m
```

Note that the -vm arg and its value must appear on separete lines and must be placed just before the -vmargs argument.